# WSO2 ESB - HTTP 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: http, wso2, http-status-code-401, wso2-esb

I have been creating a Proxy service using service chaining mechanism. 
1. First I make a call to an endpoint, get the result and send the result to a sequence. 
2. In the sequence, I have a data mapper and then a property to specify the username and password to a secure endpoint and then send mediator to call an endpoint.

However, I have been getting the following error:
HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[endpoint Url] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized,
With the description as "This request requires HTTP authentication"

The solution I have tried:
1. Tried adding a property "FORCE_HTTP_1.0" to true before making a call to the endpoint. 
But nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you set username and password? How does endpoint expect them?

Comment: Add a property Mediator and then set the username and password using base64 encoding. Refer this link: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Enabling+HTTP+Basic+Authentication+through+a+Proxy+Server

Comment: So you're saying it didn't work?

Comment: I had added the Username-password in the property but did not realize that the name of the property had to be "Authorization" only. I had given some other name and that's why it wasn't working

Comment: Glad you could resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your backend requires Basic authentication, set the following property before your backend call.

Mmh seems like it's not possible to paste Code from my iPhone. Hope the link works.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Enabling+HTTP+Basic+Authentication+through+a+Proxy+Server

Just set the property "Proxy-Authorization"

Comment: Thank you!! I had added the Username-password in the property but did not realize that the name of the property had to be "Authorization" only. I had given some other name and that's why it wasn't working.